# In what scenarios does SELECT ... FOR UPDATE work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
The document told that

> SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is to avoid inconsistencies in the table caused by other users inserting, modifying, or deleting the table while querying.

but the default Isolation level of mysql is REPEATABLE READ.
It means when a transaction is reading a row, other transaction can't write this row at the same time.

So why do we need SELECT ... FOR UPDATE?

Comment: `REPEATABLE READ` only applies to InnoDB. There is also MyISAM tables and maybe others, too.

Comment: Also while TRANSACTIONs are best practise, they are not required and there are more direct (non-transactional) ways of editing SQL data....